# Rank of matrix and one of its eigenvectors (A,v)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

All,

I encounter the following statement in one note:

"$v$ is an eigenvector of matrix $A$ " is equivalent to : rank$(A,v) \leqslant$ 2"

however, I cannot figure that how the above equivalency can hold.

I try to think from the "rank-nullity theorem", but what I can have is:

Row number of matrix $(A,v) = n+1 =$ dim$(\text{kernel}(A,v)) + \text{rank}((A,v))$,

then that means what we seek is to verify : dim$(\text{kernel}(A,v)) >= n-1$

In fact, I can construct the following relationship from the definition of the eigenvalue, i.e. assume $\lambda$ is the associated eigenvalue for $v$, then:

$$Av-\lambda v =0 \iff 
\begin{bmatrix}
    A, v \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    v  \\
    \lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}
=0
$$

But then?

Comment: Why right hand side means "$v=0$"? could you explain more? Thx~

Comment: No, forget what I said. The equality is right. Still, I don't think it is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, the assertion is clearly false. Take $A $ to be any matrix with rankmat least three, and $v $ an eigenvector for $A $. For instance, let $A=I_3$ and let $v \in\mathbb R^3$ be any nonzero vector. Then  $Av=v $, and $$\text {Rank}(A,v)=3. $$